# How to stop Javascript from cascading click events or how to assign properly to different divs.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to limit my site to one page by hiding and revealing divs on click of a navigation button. The problem I'm having is that the other buttons will not work unless I hit the first button. I also have another problem with two divs showing at once if I spam two navigation buttons quickly. Wanted to make sure that didn't happen in case a viewer went click-button-happy.

I'm still pretty new to Javascript but understand most of the basics pretty well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**The part of my HTML I'm working with:**

```
    <!-- Beginning of navigationBar ----> 
<div id = "navigationBar">

    <!-- Beginning of logoBox ----> 
    <div id ="logoBox"> 
    </div>
    <!-- End of logoBox ---->

    <!-- Beginning of menuBar ---->
    <div id ="menuBar">
        <a href= "#" id="home">Home</a>
        <a href= "#" id="designers">Designers</a>
        <a href= "#" id="elements">Elements</a>
        <a href= "#" id= "sample">Your Sample Page</a>
        <a href= "#" id="contact">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
    <!-- End of menuBar ---->
</div>
<!-- End of navigationBar ---->

<!-- Beginning of mainContent ---->
<div id="mainContent">

    <!-- Begining of Intro Page --->
    <div id= "Intro"> Intro Page content goes here.
    </div>
    <!-- End of Intro Page --->



    <!-- Begining of Home Page --->
    <div id= "Home">Home page content goes here. 
    </div>
    <!-- End of Home Page --->



    <!-- Begining of Designers Page --->
    <div id= "Designers"> Designers page content goes here. 
    </div>
    <!-- End of Designers Page --->



    <!-- Begining of Elements Page --->
    <div id= "Elements"> Elements page content goes here.
    </div>
    <!-- End of Elements Page --->



    <!-- Begining of Sample Page --->
    <div id= "Sample">Sample page content goes here. 
    </div>
    <!-- End of Sample Page --->



    <!-- Begining of Contact Page --->
    <div id= "Contact">Contact page content goes here. 
    </div>
    <!-- End of Contact Page --->
```

**The bit of CSS that has been added & working with:**

```
 #menuBar {
    padding:5px;

}
#menuBar > a{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    background:#FFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #999;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#menuBar > a:hover{
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}


#mainContent {
}
#socialMediaBar {
    background:#000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
#copyRight {
}

#Intro {
    display:none;
}

#Home {
    display:none;
}

#Designers {
    display:none;
}

#Elements {
    display:none;
}

#Sample {
    display:none;
}
```

**My javascript failing code:**

```
    window.onload=function(){
    $('#Intro').fadeIn("Slow")};


$("#home").click(function(){

    $('#Home').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Home').is(':visible')){  
    $('#Designers, #Elements, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide();}

$("#designers").click(function(){
    $('#Designers').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Designers').is(':visible')){
    $('#Home, #Elements, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#elements").click(function(){
    $('#Elements').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Elements').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#sample").click(function(){
    $('#Sample').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Sample').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Elements, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#contact").click(function(){
    $('#Contact').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Contact').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Elements, #Intro').hide()};
    });

    });
```

Comment: Youre nesting click events. That's who you need a click to trigger it

Comment: So is there a better way to go about it rather than nesting click events? Or a better way to trigger them all on load of page without them firing off their events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it totally wrong, just don't depend on `id`s of menu items, instead use the parent element `#menuBar` for event handler and use following approach (`id`'s must be unique)

```
<div id ="menuBar">
    <a href= "#" data-mainContent="home">Home</a>
    <a href= "#" data-mainContent="designers">Designers</a>
    <!-- more -->
</div>

<div id="mainContent">
    <div id= "intro">Intro content goes here.</div>
    <div id= "home">Home page content goes here.</div>
    <div id= "designers">Designer page content goes here.</div>
     <!-- more -->
</div>
```

Then in your `jQuery` code try this (only this code will do the job and don't need separate handlers)

```
$(function(){ // instead of window.onload
    $('#mainContent').children().hide();
    $('#intro').fadeIn("Slow");

    // Click event handler for all
    $('#menuBar').on('click', 'a', function(){
        $('#mainContent').children().hide();
        var el = $(this).attr('data-mainContent');
        $('#mainContent div#' + el).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Also, use of `window.onload=function(){ //... }` is wrong here. Instead you should use `document.ready` event but I've used the short form here

```
// You may Use this instead of window.onload=function(){ ... };
$(function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

[**Working Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Wjdbu/2/)

**Update:** Since there was a confusion about same `id`s being used twice but it was not because `id`'s were `Home` and `home` so because of case sensitive nature of javascript, it' valid to have `id=Home` and `id=home` on the same page for two different elements. So, using the same (case sensitive, like `Home and home`) id, [this could be done](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Wjdbu/4/).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew there was a "document.ready" but I had put window.onload in hopes that it'd stop the cascading.

Comment: @TheDigital, Check the updated demo, you have used one `id` for multiple elements and it's wrong, also `Home` and `home` both are different in JavaScript (it's case sensitive).

Comment: I'll give this one a try as well. I want to learn as much as I can about javascript. Sandro's fix for my problem did work but if there is a proper way of doing it, I'll try it out.

Comment: @TheDigital, Other answers are wrong, it's working somehow but doesn't mean it's right, an `ID` must be unique on a page and overall you don't need event handler for each element because you can use a event delegation  using the parent element, check [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Code looked much complicated but I broke it down and I see it's actually a lot more simplified. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheDigital, You are welcome and check the demo given in the answer so you'll get it clearly :-)

Comment: Oh, checked it. It's how I came to understand what you meant. Although, I'm not too sure what "el" means. So I need to look that up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all get rid of nested click event. In your code you have all click events under home click script. So obviusly other clicks wont run if you dont click home first. I moved ver last closing `});` to where it belongs.

```
$("#home").click(function(){

    $('#Home').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Home').is(':visible')){  
    $('#Designers, #Elements, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide();}
});
$("#designers").click(function(){
    $('#Designers').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Designers').is(':visible')){
    $('#Home, #Elements, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#elements").click(function(){
    $('#Elements').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Elements').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#sample").click(function(){
    $('#Sample').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Sample').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Elements, #Contact, #Intro').hide()};
    });
$("#contact").click(function(){
    $('#Contact').fadeIn("Slow");
    if($('#Contact').is(':visible')){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Elements, #Intro').hide()};
    });
```

Than you can use callback function to avoid divs showing before previous item is not hidden.

So

```
$("#contact").click(function(){
    $('#Contact').fadeIn("Slow", function(){
       $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Elements, #Intro').hide();
    });
});
```

But for click spamming problem Id do this:

```
$("#contact").click(function(){
    $('#Designers, #Home, #Sample, #Elements, #Intro').hide();
    $('#Contact').fadeIn("Slow", function(){});
});
```

Comment: So would I do this for each individual button and it wouldn't be the same as nesting? O.o

Comment: @TheDigital no, nesting problem is only for home button. You have all other clicks under it.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze, in case of `Home` and `home` it's valid but still now there is no reason for separate handlers.

Comment: [This is better](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Wjdbu/4/) using same (case sensitive) `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not hiding the contact us block in your CSS at the start, that's why when you first load your page you see the contact us content.

Check here a fixed **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/r4Duf/1/)**

```
$('#Intro').fadeIn("Slow");


$("#home").click(function () {
    $('#Designers, #Elements, #Sample, #Contact, #Intro').hide();
    $('#Home').fadeIn("Slow");
});
```

Comment: The ID's are case sensitive in case you don't know this. Having two IDs of  Home and home will result in a VALID html... Really old browser versions though like IE 6- might have a problem with this...

Comment: @Thomas, Yes in case of `Home` and `home` it's `100%` valid.

Comment: @Thomas, still now there is no reason for separate handlers.

Comment: @SheikhHeera i don't understand though what you need to be fixed... The OP is not using the same ID twice or anything (even though he is using Home/home , Intro/intro etc)

Comment: @Thomas, yes, it was my mistake and it happened because of same (but not technically same) `id`'s but it's right but still there is lot more code for this simple task.

Comment: @SheikhHeera i prefer it with separate handlers for two reasons, first we avoid 'refreshing' the same content if the button is pressed and secondly that's how the OP had it.Besides the question was not about that, you can make suggestions but not enforce your way of coding to other....

Comment: @Thomas, you are right and I'm not enforcing for that, the `id`'s looked same (confusing) but it was right.

Comment: [This is better](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Wjdbu/4/) using same (case sensitive) `id`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/Wjdbu/5/  Updated your new fiddle to avoid 'refreshing' the current content if the same button is getting clicked ;-) . +1 for your code mate.